# how to delete record using WP_List_Table in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is my code when i click on delete button page is reloed. data is not deleted .
Can YOu help me?
Here is my code when i click on delete button page is reloed. data is not deleted .
Can YOu help me?

```
class Job_List extends WP_List_Table {

    private $table_data;


    public function prepare_items() {
        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = [];
        $this->_column_headers = [$columns, $hidden];
        $data = $this->get_data(); 
        $per_page = 10;
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $total_items = count($data);
        $this->set_pagination_args([
            'total_items' => $total_items,
            'per_page'    => $per_page,
        ]);
        $data = array_slice($data, (($current_page - 1) * $per_page), $per_page);
        $this->items = $data;
    }


        public function process_bulk_action() {
 
        if ('delete' === $this->current_action()) {
            $id = absint($_GET['id']);
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'applied_job_list';
            $wpdb->delete($table_name, array('id' => $id), array('%d'));
    
            wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=' . $_GET['page']));
            exit;
        }
    }
    public function get_bulk_actions() {
        $actions = array(
            'delete' => 'Delete',
       
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    private function get_data() {
        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'applied_job_list';
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_name}", ARRAY_A);

        foreach ($results as &$result) {
            $experience = 'N/A';
            if ($result['experience'] == 0) {
                $experience = 'Fresher';
            } elseif ($result['experience'] == 1) {
                $experience = '1 Years';
            } elseif ($result['experience'] == 2) {
                $experience = '2 Years';
            } elseif ($result['experience'] == 3) {
                $experience = '3 Years';
            } elseif ($result['experience'] == 4) {
                $experience = '4 Years';
            } elseif ($result['experience'] == 5) {
                $experience = '5+ Years';
            }
            $result['experience'] = $experience;

            $post_id = $result['post_id'];
            $post = get_post($post_id);
            $result['post_id'] = $post->post_title; // Change this line

            $locations = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'location');
            foreach ($locations as $location) {
                if ($result['location'] == $location->term_id) {
                    $result['location'] = $location->name;
                    break;
                }
            }

            $jobTypes = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'job_type');
            foreach ($jobTypes as $jobType) {
                if ($result['job_type'] == $jobType->term_id) {
                    $result['job_type'] = $jobType->name;
                    break;
                }
            }

            $result['applied_position'] = $post->post_title;

            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $file_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/resume/' . $result['resume'];
            $result['resume'] = '<a href="' . $file_url . '" download> Download </a>';
            $result['action'] = '<a href="?page=' . $_GET['page'] . '&action=delete&id=' . $result['id'] . '" class="delete-link">Delete</a>';
        }

        return $results;
    }
}


unction applied_job_application() {
    $jobListTable = new Job_List();
    $jobListTable->prepare_items();
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1 class="wp-heading-inline">Applied Jobs</h1>
        <form method="post" >
            <?php
               $jobListTable->display(); 
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php

}
```

when I clcik on deldete button page is relodede I can't see any error . but record is not deleted
How can I delete recod and add pagination ?

Comment: `unction` should be `function`.